# GPU's FPS vs Monitor's Hz

Tags: display, gpu, refresh-rate

I've been thinking about 144Hz monitors and GPU's FPS. A friend of mine is always talking how he needs 144Hz monitor cause he can't stand crappy 60Hz (his old monitor broke). That got me into listening all the talk about being smooth, but in order to get right quality, you have to be 200FSP and ...

Well, but why? All that talk "'cause it is smoother", is worth nothing to me, as I accept the argument, it is, but why? From digital perspective?

At first I was thinking of a monitor as a sampling devices, but that is a flawed logic, cause that would suggest, less FPS is better. Also monitor is not sampling!

Then I thought of a monitor as an outlet in a tap. Let's assume a flow limit of say 1L/s. As you open your tap, the flow starts to increase (GPU ramps up FPS). You can see a distinct change in flow, until you reach the 1L/s. After that no matter how much you open your tap, the flow will not change. The pressure will be higher, but flow will remain.

Why would more FPS would result in better transitions?

Comment: FPS is how often the *data* to be displayed is updated. Refresh rate is how often the actual picture on the screen will get updated. If you have 60fps on 60Hz monitor, *which are completely synchronized", you will get the exact same "smoothness" as for 120fps on the same 60Hz (while synchronized to each second frame).

Comment: 120 Hz is smoother because the frames are refreshed twice as quickly vs. 60 Hz. The result becomes more evident when you have a large screen and move something like your mouse quickly across it. If you move the mouse quickly enough, you can tell that the 120 Hz monitor will display a more continuous motion than the 60 Hz. What do you mean by "200 FSP"?

Comment: You are right, his application must be able to run at 144FPS, and maintain it with vertical sync on.

Comment: Also there could be some signal processing to upscale it from whatever to 144FPS. Like TV are usually 60fps but video data is usually less than 30, and the up sampling processing does make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, yes, monitors are "sampling" the frame image at the rate they specify. This sampling may be not simultaneous across the entire screen and progresses from top to bottom, but it is still "sampling", digitizing an image in time. When the image is changing (as it is in movies or game scene emulation having fast moving objects), all artifacts of digitizing in time are still in effect. So the faster sampling is always better, up to the point when other limitations of display kicks in, such as an inherent inertia of pixel switching.

Answer (score 0):

With [v-sync enabled, the FPS](http://www.tweakguides.com/Graphics_9.html) are limited to the refresh rate. so when the monitor is 60Hz, you only get 60fps:

> When VSync is disabled, your FPS and refresh rate have no relationship
>   to each other as such. This lets your graphics card work as fast as it
>   wants, sending frames to the monitor as fast as it can draw them.
>   Whether the monitor can actually show all these frames properly or not
>   is another matter, which we've already discussed above. **Clearly if
>   disabling VSync can cause graphical glitches**, however minor they may
>   be, wouldn't it make sense to always enable VSync so that your
>   graphics card doesn't wind up wasting its efforts only to generate
>   more tearing? Well once again, things are not as simple as that.
>
> When VSync is enabled, what happens is that your graphics card is told
>   to wait for your monitor to signal when it's ready for a new frame
>   before supplying a single whole frame, each and every time. It can't
>   race ahead, it can't just pump out lots of partially completed frames
>   over old ones whenever it's ready - it has to provide a single whole
>   frame to the monitor whenever the monitor says it's ready to refresh
>   itself during VBI. **The first noticeable impact is that your FPS
>   becomes capped at a maximum equal to your current refresh rate. So if
>   your refresh rate is 60Hz for example, your framerate can now only
>   reach a maximum of 60FPS.**

So if he wants to play games at 100FPS, he needs a monitor with a higher Hz number. V-Sync has some issues, so that AMD and nVIDIA created technologies to sync Refresh Rate and FPS at lower and higher values. AMD calls it [Freesync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeSync) and nVIDIA [G-Sync](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia_G-Sync).